# Laravel - Load different .env file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I need to load a different .env file, named *.env.test* under certain conditions.

I attempted to do that through a middleware by adding

```
app()->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.test');
Dotenv::create(base_path(), '.env.test')->overload();
```

to the `bootstrap()` method of *Kernel.php*. I also tried to create a dedicated middleware for this and load it as the first one in the *web* middleware group. But either way, it is loading the standard .env file.

It works if I do it in the */bootstrap/app.php* file but I really don't want to put it there.

Comment: Do you want to load .env.test file instead of .env or both files?

Comment: Have you made sure you aren't caching your configuration? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching

Comment: It will always load the `.env` file. You can load additional files using the code you've shared. I don't think you can choose a different .env file to load at the middleware stage though, the .env file has already been loaded at that point

Comment: @HiKangg: I want to load it instead of the default one

Comment: @miken32: No, it is not cached

Comment: @apokryfos From what I understand, the dotenv overload() method should take care of that?

Comment: Overload *should* overwrite environment variables from your `.env.test` file that have already been loaded via the `.env` file (in addition to loading new variables that were not loaded before). Is that not working?

Comment: @apokryfos: It depends how you look at it. It works if I access the environment variable inside of a controller. What I want to accomplish though, is to make sure that the .env.test file is used for the sessions, meaning that it should use the APP_KEY from the .env.test file instead of the default .env file

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say the problem is that the application config is already generated by the time the middleware is run, as @apokryfos says. Nothing is pulling directly from the `.env` file except for things in the `config` directory.

Comment: I just found the solution, see the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just figured it out: The default .env file is being loaded inside of the `bootstrap()` method of *LoadEnvironmentVariables.php*.

To use the .env.test file I had to restructure my initial `bootstrap()` method inside of the *App/Http/Kernel.php* file to look like this:

```
public function bootstrap() 
{
    app()->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.test');
    parent::bootstrap(); 
}
```

So the essential part was to move the `parent::bootstrap()` call below the `loadEnvironmentFrom()` call.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of doing any code change, you can use export command create a file called .env.test, you want to sue this as .env file use terminal

1. `APP_ENV=local`
2. `php artisan config:cache`
3. `php artisan key:generate`

This below edit is to explain how .env file is getting set
In `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` class has method `loadEnvironmentFrom` which is taking the file as parameter and setting it,

you can use `bootstrap/app.php` after you are getting `$app`

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
 );
```

here you will be having instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application

you can just call the loadEnvironmentFrom function like

```
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.local');
```

May be it is better to use Kernel.php instead of this, I do not think either of bootstrap/app.php or kernel.php will get overridden with `composer update`, so make more calculation while using it. I have added this, so that it will help you understand the stuffs.

Comment: My answer does not involve changing anything inside a vendor file. This obviously a no go.

Comment: @TheNiceGuy where you are making changes, can you let me know?

Comment: got it, you are changing kernel.php .

Comment: I mentioned it in my answer: Kernel.php file (where the middlewares are being configured) :)

Comment: Yep, exactly! :)

Comment: @TheNiceGuy try updated answer, this is also a good option.

Comment: I'm aware that you can define a different environment at the server layer, that won't be possible for this project though.

Comment: @TheNiceGuy may I know why this is not possible for this project may be that will help me later, but this is a cool one.

Comment: Because the clients might not have access to that. Therefore I am happy with my solution.  Thanks anyways!  :)

Comment: @TheNiceGuy hope both way will help future visitors.

Comment: another alternative is put in public/index.php after have variable $app

Answer (score 2):

You can load a different environment file using `APP_ENV`

For example if `APP_ENV=test` then `.env.test` can be loaded.

More info: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadEnvironmentVariables.php#L41

Comment: Please share more details, like the code that helps to load a different environment

Answer (score 0):

I also tried `$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.dev');` for dev, staging, and production but I don't want to change code in `bootstrap/app.php` Then I have an idea, you can try this.

I create 3 environment files (.env.dev, .env.staging, .env.production).
When I want to change the environment I run the copy command of Linux like this:
`cp .env.dev .env` or `cp .env.staging .env` ...

Remember to add your new env files to the .gitignore file

Hope this helps