Laravel 11 wont read env file according to environment
Laravel 11 won't read my .env file according to the environment.
.env
APP_ENV=local
TEST_VAR=a

.env.local
TEST_VAR=l

.env.prod
TEST_VAR=p

I'm getting TEST_VAR from code that always returns with a, no matter the value of APP_ENV. I supposed there are the configs, and environment-specific configs will overwrite them?

Would https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/configuration#configuration-caching help?

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/configuration#additional-environment-files - It's not going to load extra .env files automatically. It can if you add the --env argument on the command line, or set it somewhere else.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64174934/laravel-load-different-env-file might be of help

Does this answer your question? Laravel - Load different .env file

almost.... I made a App\Http\Kernel.php but it never executes

You can do this in your bootstrap/app.php file.
